# Change svn+ssh default username

Tags: svn, ssh, default

So I am trying to download a package using svn+ssh, and the username on my computer is different than my username for the server I'm trying to log in to.  I know that I can just do:

```
svn co svn+ssh://username@ser.ver/...
```

but I would like to change the default username so I can just do

```
svn co svn+ssh://ser.ver/...
```

Someone set it up for me that way on my old machine, but I no longer have access to it, and I don't know how to do it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using OpenSSH and are on a Unix OS then you'd edit `~/.ssh/config` and add an entry like this:

```
Host ser.ver
    User username
```

This is documented in the [ssh_config man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).  But just searching for ssh config should find you tons of answers.